# would have done or had done

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

I would have appreciated it if my colleagues had done the same for me.

I would have appreciated it if my colleagues would have done the same for me.

Is the second sentence correct?

Comment: In the second sentence, the second 'would' does not have any condition. The first sentence is good.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Weather Vane.